# Modify regex to not match a dot character

Tags: php, regex

How can this regex `\.[^\.]*}` be modified so it won't match a `.` in between the `.` & `}`?

Eg: When run against the string below, it starts from `.png`. It actually should start from `.header`

It's clearer in the [example](https://regex101.com/r/75LHpq/1)

```
.header {
    background: no-repeat url(0ffe4313f8b7667a4bf7df304b0fdf75.png) 0 -126px;
    -webkit-background-size: 307px 472px;
    background-size: 307px 472px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to parse CSS with regex?

Comment: ...and what exactly are you trying to parse out?

Comment: There's probably not a good reason to try and parse CSS with regex but I think you meant `\.[^}]*\}` anyway.

Comment: Do you notice that the dot in `.png` is the first dot before the `}` ? you try to match a dot, and then any character which is not a dot. That's why you get the last dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?sm)^\..*?}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4PIyQr/2).

**Details**:

- `(?sm)` - a DOTALL and MULTILINE inline modifiers enable `.` to match across lines (`s`) and redefine the `^` and `$` anchors to match *line* boundaries (`m`)
- `^` - start of a line
- `\.` - a dot
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `}$` - a `}` at the end of a line.

Comment: Nice, but won't work if it's all on a single line.

Comment: @Norman Then remove `^` before `}`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/4PIyQr/2).